# Install 12.10 to an external USB hard drive automatically mounted at /cdrom

Tags: installation, 12.10, external-hdd, ubiquity

how can I install Ubuntu 12.10 to an external USB HDD?

On the disc partitioning screen of the installer there is only `/dev/sda` showing up in the list. However in a terminal window I can see `/dev/sdb` with `sudo fdisk -l`. So how can I get ubiquiti to show `/dev/sdb` as well?

[image]

Comment: Does any of the information here help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/52274/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-external-hard-disk?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the USB drive is not mounted.

Try unplugging it and plugging it back in, or use Disc Utility to check it is mounted.

EDIT :

From the picture it looks like the USB drive has the wrong mount point as `/cdrom`.
It should be automatically mounted at `/media/name-of-drive`.
This is why the installer does not see it.

Have a look at [comment #6 in this old bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal/+bug/200287) and see if it helps.

### Solution

The simple solution is not to connect the USB HDD until after the live 12.10 CD boots up completely.

Comment: It is already mounted, see the attached screenshot.

Comment: You are right. Somehow the USB HDD get mounted as /cdrom, probably because an older version of Ubuntu was on it.
The simple solution is to only attach the USB hdd after the live 12.10 CD booted up completely. Thank you!

Comment: @medve - thanks for the feedback and saying what worked for you. I have added the extra info to the answer to help others, glad it's working now. :o)

Answer (score 0):

You did click on the dropdown box in the top right, right ?

See [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers/2009/gparted-sample-layout.jpg) for the dropdown box with **/dev/sda** selected.

Comment: Yes, it is there, but not in the install screen. See attached screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, it's not gparted in the install process .. It should look like [that](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/UbuntuExt1-600x414.png) instead.